# Lithium: how to get layout/template path value from Helper

Tags: lithium

I have a helper class which extends \lithium\template\Helper. How can I know which layout file/path are used to render?

Thank you.

update:
The reason I need this is because I want the site support multiple template packs.
The template layout will support render by block modules (likes Joomla template), so in the layout file I can do this:

```
<?php if($this->Block->countModule('slider')){ ?>
<div id="slider">
    <?php echo $this->Block->renderBlock('slider'); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

To add a module to a block I do this:

```
$this->Block->addModule('slider', array('element'=>'slider'));
```

........................

I have to overwrite the renderer object
in bootstrap/media.php

```
Media::type('html', 'text/html', array(
   'view' => 'app\extensions\template\View'
));
```

I created new file /app/extensions/template/View.php

```
class View extends \lithium\template\View {
    public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
        $defaults = array(
            'renderer' => 'app\extensions\template\view\adapter\File'
        );
        parent::__construct($config + $defaults);
    }
}
```

And finally the /app/extensions/template/adapter/File.php

```
class File extends \lithium\template\view\adapter\File {
    public function getTemplatePath(){
        $path = $this->_paths['layout'][0];
        $path = preg_replace('/\/\{:layout\}.*$/', '', $path);
        return $path;
    }
}
```

Now I can get the path.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for updating your question with more information. I don't quite understand the use for `getTemplatePath()` though. Are you trying to figure out how to get the path to the element template that was passed in the `addModule()` options? Can you just use `$this->_render('element', $template)` in your Block helper? That will use the Media class to find the template path and render it to html - http://li3.me/docs/lithium/template/view/Renderer::_render()

Comment: Thank you for your question. I can't call $this->_render in the block helper. It doesn't work. I also tried call $this->_contect->_render function and it doesn't work either.
I have to do this to render element:
    $view = $this->_context->view();
Then I call
    $view->render('element', $params);
The reason I want to get the template path is I want each template pack can has different ways to render a block (module position in Joomla). So I define a ModuleRenderer class then put that file in the template folder.
I works with Joomla many years and I like the way it renders the template.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you post a link to the Joomla documentation that describes this functionality? I can see if there's a cleaner way to do it in lithium.

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template
On the Body Section, you can see it loads positions by name (top, bottom, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back and interpreting your question as "How do I replicate Joomla! template module positions in Lithium PHP?", I came up with this solution.

See https://gist.github.com/rmarscher/10020347

Create a view helper at `app\extensions\helper\Module` with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace app\extensions\helper;

use lithium\core\Libraries;
use lithium\template\view\TemplateException;
use lithium\template\View;

/**
 * An implementation of Joomla! template module positions for Lithium.
 *
 * Here is how you can render to a module position from one of your inner templates:
 * {{{
 * $this->modules->bottom("element", 'bottomTest');
 * $this->modules->top("simple", "<p>Maybe we can just put some html in there...</p>");
 * }}}
 *
 * To do the same from inside another helper, use `$this->_context->modules()`.
 *
 * Then in your layout file, output the module in the desired location:
 * {{{
 * <body>
 * <?php echo $this->modules->top(); ?>
 * <?php echo $this->content(); ?>
 * <?php echo $this->modules->bottom(); ?>
 * </body>
 * }}}
 *
 * @see http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template#Body_Section
 */
class Modules extends \lithium\template\Helper {

    protected $_rendered = array();
    protected $_simpleView = null;

    public function __call($name, $params) {
        return $this->position($name, $params);
    }

    public function position($name, $params) {
        if (empty($this->_rendered[$name])) {
            $this->_rendered[$name] = "";
        }
        switch (count($params)) {
            case 0:
                return $this->_rendered[$name];
            case 1:
                return $this->_rendered[$name] .= $this->render($params[0]);
            case 2:
                return $this->_rendered[$name] .= $this->render($params[0], $params[1]);
            case 3:
                return $this->_rendered[$name] .= $this->render($params[0], $params[1], $params[2]);
            case 4:
                return $this->_rendered[$name] .= $this->render($params[0], $params[1], $params[2], $params[3]);
            case 5:
                return $this->_rendered[$name] .= $this->render($params[0], $params[1], $params[2], $params[3], $params[4]);
            default:
                return $this->_rendered[$name] .= call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $method), $params);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut method used to render elements and other nested templates for named module blocks.
     *
     * @see lithium\template\View::render()
     * @param string $type The type of template to render, usually either `'element'` or
     *               `'template'`. Indicates the process used to render the content. See
     *               `lithium\template\View::$_processes` for more info.
     *               There's an additional special option here for the Modules helper.
     *               Use `"simple"` to render a string template rather than from a file.
     * @param string $template The template file name. For example, if `'header'` is passed, and
     *               `$type` is set to `'element'`, then the template rendered will be
     *               `views/elements/header.html.php` (assuming the default configuration).
     *               If `$type === 'simple'`, this should be the template content.
     * @param array $data An array of any other local variables that should be injected into the
     *              template. By default, only the values used to render the current template will
     *              be sent. If `$data` is non-empty, both sets of variables will be merged.
     * @param array $options Any options accepted by `template\View::render()`.
     * @return string Returns a the rendered template content as a string.
     */
    public function render($type, $template, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
        $view = $this->_context->view();
        if ($type !== "simple") {
            return $view->render($type, $data, compact('template') + $options);
        }
        if (!$this->_simpleView) {
            $this->_simpleView = new View(array('loader' => 'Simple', 'renderer' => 'Simple'));
        }
        $element = $template;
        return $this->_simpleView->render('element', $data, compact('element') + $options);
    }

}

?>
```

Then you can do this in your templates to render to a module position:

```
<?=$this->_render("element", "elementTest"); ?>
<?php $this->modules->top("element", 'topTest'); ?>
<?php $this->modules->bottom("element", 'bottomTest'); ?>
<h1>Hi there. I'm the main content.</h1>
<?php $this->modules->top("simple", "<p>Maybe we can just put some html in there...</p>");
```

And then do this in your layout template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->html->charset();?>
    <title><?php echo $this->title(); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <?php echo $this->modules->top(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->content(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->modules->bottom(); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's very similar to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the template path by passing `__FILE__` in an argument to your helper function.

There also seems to be an internal `$template__` variable available in your templates.

See http://li3.me/docs/lithium/template/view/adapter/File::render().

The Renderer object is also available in your helper as `$this->_context`. I don't think it stores state about which file is being rendered.

Comment: I tried the $this->_context renderer object but all variables which store information about layout/template paths is protected and not accessible.
So I have to overwrite the renderer object